# how to move back from a current directory

Tags: command-line, directory, cd-command

Hi if suppose I am curently here:

```
cd Desktop/kinectrobot/src/beginner_tutorials/src
```

and after that working in  src i want to move back one directory 
for example I want to go to **beginner_tutorials**.
How do I do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`.` is the directory where you are.

`..` is your directory's parent.

So the command would be `cd ..`

Answer (score 1):

another little know trick

you are in `Desktop/kinectrobot/src/beginner_tutorials/src`

you change dir to `/var/www/myDoc`

```
cd /var/www/myDoc
```

to "return" to Desktop/kinectrobot/src/beginner_tutorials/src, simply do

```
cd -
```

using `cd -` will swap you to the directory you were before.

you may also wish to use `pushd` and `popd`.

Answer (score 0):

Simply do :

```
cd ..
```

See [man cd](http://linuxcommand.org/lc3_man_pages/cdh.html) for more information.

Answer (score 0):

C++ got me addicted to the power of the closing bracket:

```
(
  cd "$targetDirectory"
  #...
) 
# Whatever (almost) happened in the address space of the subshell
# won't have any effect here
```